# VMwarePlayer on debian. Missing kernel modules

Tags: linux, vmware, kernel-module

Today I changed my workstation to Debian. As Ubuntu is not nearly stable. Now I installed VMware player. I started it and got a message "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and and loaded into the running kernel. Kernel headers for version2.6.32-5-amd64 were not found" , below a field were I can give a file location. What should I do now? I never faced such a situation.

Comment: I'd try installing the build-essential package... `apt-get install build-essential`; that usually fixes these kinds of issues for me. Then re-run the VMWare player executable that gave you the error message. I use VBox so I'm just guessing here. It's clear you need the kernel-headers, but it probably also requires `gcc` and all the other complier goodies to compile a kernel module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

Did the trick.